# Use VBA to Insert a Word File From its Shortcut

Tags: vba, shortcut

How can a Word file be inserted programmatically by using a shortcut? Our company needs to mix and match source files into larger release documents, and a single file may be used in multiple release documents.

The approach is to have one copy of a source file. Then, each release document has its own directory containing shortcuts to all the source files it should contain.  To sort them in proper order, the shortcut names have a prefix number, which means that the shortcut has a different name from the source file.

This works fine when I use the actual path and file name, but I get an error when using a shortcut:
Run-time error '5273': The document name or path is not valid.

I am using the code:

```
Dim strSourceFolder As String   'location of source files

    ChangeFileOpenDirectory strSourceFolder

    Selection.InsertFile FileName:=  strSourceFolder & "[#-SHORTCUT NAME HERE].docx" _, Range:="", ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts contain the folder and file name (right-click Properties and see Target path) so you have some redundancy. Also, shortcuts do not contain file extensions. Therefore, just leave shortcut name for the FileName:

```
Selection.InsertFile FileName:="[#-SHORTCUT NAME HERE]" _, 
Range:="", ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait, As much as I appreciate the help, I still can't get it to work. I now get a different error "Run-time error '5174': This file could not be found," so I guess that is progress.
Leaving off the path works when I use a real file (rather than a shortcut), but that is not what we need to do. I have also tried it both with and without the file extension. Any additional suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: John, I just checked on my end and successfully inserted a doc using a shortcut without file  extension. Just to be sure, the shortcut must exist inside the specified folder strSourcefolder (but not necessarily the file it targets).

Comment: Thanks. It is reassuring to know that it will work at all. No luck on my end. I have moved the directories to my local hard drive, even shortened the shortcut name to "Test." Have now put a ticket into our IT group, thinking there may be something strange about the configuration of my computer.  New information comes from recording a macro. The recording shows the path and file name of the target, rather than the shortcut. I will add it in another comment.

Comment: I can't seem to add formatted code to a comment. In any case, I will report back when I hear from our IT folks. If nothing else, I will just record the macros and go with the target information that is recorded in the code.
Thanks again.